# How to have a "sticky" phone number format place holder on form?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show format of the phone number in the form as a placeholder and not get erased as the user types the number.

html placeholder dissapears as the user types. I want the placeholder to stay and lead the user as they type phone number.

```
<form action="payonline.html">
     <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" required placeholder="___ - ___ - ____ ">                             
       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: I think what you're looking for is an input mask, where it shows something like `(___) ___-____`? There are many masking libraries, I don't think there's any built-in browser support.

Comment: Google "javascript input mask" and you'll find them.

Comment: I'm curious about the reasons that lead someone to upvote this question. It doesn't show any effort to solve the issue, nothing even researched on google or on SO. It's the classic "write it for me"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use onkeypress and onkeyup event in javascript to create a phone input more user friendly.
You can use code below.Im not sure you using jquery so i use pure javascript.

```
<form action="payonline.html">
     <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" required placeholder="___ - ___ - ____ " onkeypress="validate_int(this)" onkeyup="phone_number_mask()">                             
       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
<script>

 function validate_int(myEvento) {
  if ((myEvento.charCode >= 48 && myEvento.charCode <= 57) || myEvento.keyCode == 9 || myEvento.keyCode == 10 || myEvento.keyCode == 13 || myEvento.keyCode == 8 || myEvento.keyCode == 116 || myEvento.keyCode == 46 || (myEvento.keyCode <= 40 && myEvento.keyCode >= 37)) {
    dato = true;
  } else {
    dato = false;
  }
  return dato;
}
function phone_number_mask() {
      var myMask = "___-___-____";
      var myCaja = document.getElementById("phone");
      var myText = "";
      var myNumbers = [];
      var myOutPut = ""
      var theLastPos = 1;
      myText = myCaja.value;
      //get numbers
      for (var i = 0; i < myText.length; i++) {
        if (!isNaN(myText.charAt(i)) && myText.charAt(i) != " ") {
          myNumbers.push(myText.charAt(i));
        }
      }
      //write over mask
      for (var j = 0; j < myMask.length; j++) {
        if (myMask.charAt(j) == "_") { //replace "_" by a number 
          if (myNumbers.length == 0)
            myOutPut = myOutPut + myMask.charAt(j);
          else {
            myOutPut = myOutPut + myNumbers.shift();
            theLastPos = j + 1; //set caret position
          }
        } else {
          myOutPut = myOutPut + myMask.charAt(j);
        }
      }
      document.getElementById("phone").value = myOutPut;
      document.getElementById("phone").setSelectionRange(theLastPos, theLastPos);
    }


</script>
```